# Does the Mage Slayer feat impose disadvantage on concentration saves from all damage you deal, or only if damaged by the feat's reaction attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, attack, concentration, dnd-beyond

According to my character sheet on D&D Beyond, the Mage Slayer feat says:

> When a creature within 5 ft. of you casts a spell, you can use your reaction to make a melee weapon attack against that creature, **and when you damage a creature that is concentrating on a spell**, that creature has disadvantage on the saving throw it makes to maintain its concentration. You also have advantage on saving throws against spells cast by creatures within 5 ft. of you.

Say a mage is concentrating on a spell. If this player character hits the mage with the Attack action on the player character's turn, does the mage have disadvantage on that Con saving throw to maintain concentration?

Or does the caster only have disadvantage on the Con save to maintain concentration if damaged by the reaction attack that is triggered by a spell being cast by the mage within 5 feet of the player character?

Comment: [Mage Slayer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/mage-slayer) DDB doesn't match what you've got here either.

Comment: I got it directly from the tooltip text from the character sheet, seems thats an abbreviated version.

Comment: Ah, I see that now; clicking on the text box for it from the character sheet brings up the full text on the right.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## On all attacks

Each bullet point of the [Mage Slayer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/mage-slayer) feat (PHB, pg. 168) is a separate benefit:

> - When a creature within 5 feet of you casts a spell, you can use your reaction to make a melee weapon attack against that creature.
> - When you damage a creature that is concentrating on a spell, that creature has disadvantage on the saving throw it makes to maintain its concentration.
> - [...]

As long as you attack a creature who is concentrating on a spell, you can force disadvantage on the Constitution saving throw they make to maintain concentration.

The prior bullet point simply grants you a reaction attack if a creature within 5 feet of you casts a spell. Although if you hit, and the creature is concentrating on a spell, then they would have disadvantage on their concentration save per the second bullet point.

Answer (score 6):

### All attacks

I’m not sure where your quote is from, but that is *not* how the feature appears in the PHB. In my version of the PHB this feat appears on page 168 and all 3 of these (reaction attacks against casters, imposing disadvantage on concentration, advantage on saves from spells within 5ft) are listed as separate benefits in a bullet list.

Comment: According to a comment on the question, the erroneous quote was because the querent was looking at the "snippet" of the feat description on the character sheet, rather than the full description of the feat that appears in the sidebar if that part of the sheet is clicked (and appears in the compendium/standalone feat listings as well). That said, you may want to elaborate on your answer a bit more to better support it/explain the logic.